# Draw lines with Sprite kit and swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, drawing, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite kit with Swift to assay drawing lines with fingers.

Code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
    firstPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
    var positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)

    lineNode.removeFromParent()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y)
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw
    lineNode.lineWidth = 10.0
    lineNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.addChild(lineNode)
    firstPoint = positionInScene
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

}
```

But the lines obtained are empty, only the border has color (image).

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What type is `lineNode`?

Comment: var lineNode = SKShapeNode()

Comment: When using `CAShapeLayer` I have had success by also setting the `fillColor`.

Comment: How dow you use CAShapeLayer? Could you post some example code?

Comment: Have you tried running that on an actual device? I've seen some weird bugs with SpriteKit and stroking paths in the simulator.

Comment: No, I've tied only in the simulator. I'll try in a real device. Thanks.

Comment: From Apple's SKShapeNode documentation: "A line width larger than 2.0 may cause rendering artifacts in the final rendered image."

Comment: I know those artifacts, but only have appeared in simulator. As Mike S has proposed, I've tried in a device and it works fine. Anyway, more tests will be necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @RFG Where do you define pathToDraw ?

Answer (score 2):

`SKShapeNode` has a property called `fillColor` which is by default set to `clearColor`. In your code, you only set the `strokeColor`(outline) to red, but you should also do so to `fillColor`.

You can do this with `lineNode.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Good luck!